# Nested element to center correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of li-elements that are positioned/displayed with inline-block and therefore with vertical-align-top.

In these li-elements I do use hidden checkboxes and labels for the actual content. The li-elements have a given fixed height and I now want to center the label-elements vertically correct within these by vertical-align:middle or baseline.

But none of these does work and I don't really get why, because this would somehow make quite sense for these nested elements. The code looks a bit like this:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="foo">
    <label for="foo">Content of the element to be positioned at the center of it</label>
</li>
```

And the css is like

```
li {
    background:orange;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    height:60px;
    padding:0 12px;
}
li input{
    display:none;
}
li label{
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align:middle; /*doesn't work, but this should be the actual behaviour */
}
```

What would I instead of vertical-align need to use here? And why?

Comment: why not you can use line-height:60px; for li?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `line-height`, as the `height` of the `li` is *fixed*, you can set the same as `line-height`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/jdnab672/1/)

```css
li {
  background: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 12px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
li input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="foo">
  <label for="foo">Content of the element to be positioned at the center of it</label>
</li>
```

Comment: yeah, I would also be interested in the reason of why downvoting that?

Comment: And me too. I hate when people downvote and don't tell the reason. Downvoter, can something be improved?

Comment: @Daiaiai if it's works for you then up vote and accept it

Comment: @akash Sure. But maybe somehwen a downvoter has had a good reason for downvoting that and I'd be interested in hearing what the reason was

Answer (score 0):

Try flex layout.

```css
li {
    background:orange;
    display:flex;
    height:60px;
    padding:0 12px;
    justify-content: center; /* remove this line if u only want vertical center*/
    align-items: center;
}
li input{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="foo">
    <label for="foo">Content of the element to be positioned at the center of it</label>
</li>
```